# how to disable nginx proxy buffer in elastic beanstalk nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i keep getting the following errors:

> 2022/12/18 04:04:00 [warn] 9797#9797: *3712915 an upstream response is
> buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/5/07/0000015075
> while reading upstream, client: 10.8.5.39, server: , request: "GET
> /api/test HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/test", host:
> "cms-api.internal.testtest.com"

so i decided to disable proxy buffer since its a server to server communication within the LAN, not a slower client. asking EC2 support is useless they just told me they dont support nginx - DUH.

found a great article on how to calculate buffers, etc. https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx
I set the following ebextension the following settings.

```
client_body_buffer_size 100M;
client_max_body_size 100M;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 100 128k;
```

realise still having same issue. Initially i tried to adjust buffer size, but it didnt work, than i outright turned it off, still having same issue. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set the following ebextension the following settings

That's why it does not work. For configuring nginx you **have to use** `.platform`, not `.ebextension`, as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). So you have to create a file, e.g.

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf
```

wit content

```
client_body_buffer_size 100M;
client_max_body_size 100M;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 100 128k;
```